# How to access a SwipeView open method in a content page from another xaml codebehind

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, code-behind

I have a parent `ContentPage` which has a `SwipeView` in it, with a `x:Name MainSwipe` identifier, is it possible to call this particular `SwipeView` to open and close from another xaml code-behind using `MainSwipe.Open()`, just as I could do from the original parent `ContentPage` code-behind.

Comment: MessagingCenter in XF could probably get you there

Comment: If you use `MessagingCenter` to execute `MainSwipe.Open()` in the other pages, MainSwipe will not update view, If you reopen the `MainSwipe`'s view.  `MainSwipe.Open()` is worked when you in the `MainSwipe`'s view. Not in other pages.https://imgur.com/a/Q3MI0GE